Can anyone explain what this await useState React code does?
I found some react code that modifies React state directly. I was taught that this is a big coding sin. However, when trying to update it, the functionality breaks. Obviously, I need to fix that, but I was wondering If I could get an explanation as to what this code is doing, so I can better refactor it?
const removeIndex = selectedCheckList.findIndex(
  (selectedVisit) => selectedVisit.visitId == selectedcheckItem.visitId,
)

const removeKeyIndex = RowValue.findIndex(
  (selectedVisitRowIndex) => selectedVisitRowIndex == keyIndex,
)

await selectedCheckList.splice(removeIndex, 1)
await RowValue.splice(removeKeyIndex, 1)

setSelectedCheckList(selectedCheckList)
setRowValue(RowValue)

I tried to make the checks be inline on a setState call, I also tried to move the set to the end since refactors happen in batches, I also tried making new local variables to hold the state update, and then using those in the setState calls, but nothing worked.
So question - what do these awaits do against useState, and how are they interpreted?

Those awaits look completely useless, since array splice does not return a promise. The only way i could see it doing anything is if it was surrounded by code which is very fragile and depends heavily on the exact order of execution.

Another thought is that if this is in react 17 or earlier, the awaits would cause react's batching logic to break. Doing that intentionally would again be a weird and fragile thing to do, but it would be a way to force a synchronous render. I think the simplest explanation is that the awaits are just a mistake.

if I take them out, my checkboxes stop working, so I feel inclined to agree with your comment that it is intentionally trying to force a synchronous render

Interesting... That code is probably pretty fragile as other comments said, and maybe "dirty", but I still find this an interesting problem. Maybe the question can improved to make the point clearer, but I'm not sure how. Maybe add the corresponding useState lines ? Maybe show a the full component that illustrates the problem ? (without any irrelevant code, of course).

The await:
The await keyword would "delay" the execution of the following code "just a little bit" in a very hacky way.
More precisely, a new microtask is created, that allows some other code to execute earlier. This possibly "other code" is not visible in this question, so a full analysis of what's happening is not possible.
A guess would be that this await is supposed to overrule some react specific execution order, which is definitively a bad idea (I would even call this "wrong", IMO), because this relies on the internal behavior of React, which may change and does change sometimes.
Modifying state
You are right, modifying the state is a bad idea too. Technically you can do that if you know what you are doing, and everything works fine, but it makes the code confusing and error prone.
In your example a quick "improvement" would be to copy the state before calling splice. That makes no difference technically (unless selectedCheckList and/or RowValue are used somewhere else in some way), but IMO makes the code more understandable, and might make it easier to continue with further refactoring. E.g.:
const copiedChecklist = [ ...selectedCheckList ];
const copiedRowValue = [ ...RowValue ];

// (Note that I'm ignoring the `await`-problem here, and keep that as it was)
await copiedChecklist.splice( removeIndex, 1 );
await copiedRowValue.splice( removeKeyIndex, 1 ); 

setSelectedCheckList( copiedChecklist )
setRowValue( copiedRowValue )

